# how to install window 10 with CentOS

Tags: centos, windows, dual-boot

I have installed CentOS in my system. I am using this for long time. I have 3 drives on my system.

- First root computer
- Second for my data
- third is also for data

I have some space in the first drive which is root. Can I install the Window 10 with this? I already used Virtual box for using window 10. I am not comfortable using this. It requires  a lot of main memory and process speed. Can I make dual boot with Window 10? I don't want to lose my data.  I tried many solutions. Nothing works.

I already used the Ubuntu 14.04LTS with Window 10. It is really easy to install Ubuntu 14.04 with Window.

I have used these references.

- [Installing CentOS 7.1 Dual Boot With Windows 8.1 on UEFI Firmware Systems](http://www.tecmint.com/install-centos-7-dual-boot-with-windows-8-uefi-firmware/)
- [Install Window 7 after CentOS](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3037)

Comment: First: think about what you need: Shared files in a partition? Which should be the main system? Which OS should get how much space? If the CentOS is already installed and the file system set, things are more complicated, it's easier to start form a clean install without keeping data. Check if that is possible.

Comment: I don't understand. why people are giving the down vote for this questions. Is there some problem in this question?

Comment: The question is too broad and does not properly point out your problem setting: make sure to mention a) CentOS is already installed and windows MUST be installed after without destroying the CentOS install, b) if you have free capacities in terms of partitions or even whole hard drives, c) maybe that you are aware that the reverse order (wind first, then CentOS) is simple but that you need it otherwise, d) mention if you did internet research before/ what you already tried and where you are stuck. Otherwise the problem is not specific enough to give a simple or proper answer.

Comment: This is pretty good to know. I improve the question. So, I can get the proper answer. is it good? @Fiximan

Comment: Yes, much better. Now I'd suggest you do as Atay Özcan sais: Free a partition, install Windows, and then you most likely will have to reinstall your bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Make a empty partition with gparted and boot from windiws disk then select empty partition to install and install